# How to read the body of a Message object when implementing IDispatchMessageFormatter for custom (de)serialization of a WCF REST service?

Tags: wcf, json, serialization, wcf-binding

I am extending [`WebHttpBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.webhttpbehavior.aspx) to expose a WCF REST service with customized serialization and deserialization (plus a certain number of other features that are not relevant to the problem).

The new behavior uses an implementation of [`IDispatchMessageFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageformatter.aspx) to perform custom serialization and deserialization of POCOs served by the service and sent to it thanks to the [`SerializeReply`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageformatter.serializereply.aspx) and [`DeserializeRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageformatter.deserializerequest.aspx) methods.

I can serve XML and JSON exactly how I need them in `SerializeReply`.

I can deserialize XML without a problem, however I can't seem to find the way to deserialize a JSON message because I can't obtain the plain text contained in the [`Message`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.aspx) parameter of `DeserializeRequest`.

This is what the code in `DeserializeRequest` looks like right now:

```
if (format == System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json)
{
    var data = ""; // TODO obtain plain text from Message object

    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, paramType, new IsoDateTimeConverter(), new StringEnumConverter());

    parameters[paramIndex] = json;
}
else
{
    var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(paramType, string.Empty);

    var reader = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents();

    parameters[paramIndex] = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

I'm using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) for JSON (de)serialization.

Any suggestions on how to obtain plain text from the `Message` object in order to deserialize it would be greatly appreciated.

If you think there's something wrong in my approach I'd also like to hear of it in the comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `WebMessageFormat` of the Message is set to **Raw**, otherwise WCF will use a the `JsonMessageEncoder` in order to create the `Message` which in turn won't allow you to get to the raw message content.

You do that by implementing a custom `WebContentTypeMapper`:

```
public class RawMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
{
    public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
    {
        return WebContentFormat.Raw;
    }
}
```

...which needs to be applied to the WebHttpBinding:

```
webHttpBinding.ContentTypeMapper = new RawMapper();
```

..or via configuration:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding contentTypeMapper="Samples.RawMapper, MyContentTypeMapperAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

With that in place, you can then retrieve the request body as a String like that:

```
    public void DeserializeRequest(Message message, object[] parameters)
    {
        var bodyReader = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
        bodyReader.ReadStartElement("Binary");
        byte[] rawBody = bodyReader.ReadContentAsBase64();

        string messageAsString;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(rawBody)))
            messageAsString = reader.ReadToEnd();

        object jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(messageAsString);

        parameters[0] = jsonObj;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Even if you are using WebMessageFormat.Json you can convert your message to string and then deserialize it to object inside DeserializeRequest method.

```cs
MemoryStream mss = new MemoryStream();
XmlDictionaryWriter writer = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(mss);
message.WriteMessage(writer);
writer.Flush();
string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mss.ToArray());

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(messageBody, operation.Messages[0].Body.Parts[0].Type);

parameters[0] = obj;
```